# Deployment script to apache, permissions problem

Tags: django, linux, apache, mina-deploy

I'm developing a Django application that is being deployed to an apache server.

I'm using two servers right now. In one server I have the Development and Staging instances for which I use a bash shell script to deploy, and in the other server the Production instance in which I use a mina-deploy script.

The problem comes after deploying since the permissions on the /var/www/... folder are not correct after the deployment, this wont allow apache to serve the website.

I was wondering if there is anyway I can deploy this code without making any change to permissions. For both I'm not using a root user but an user with SUDO permissions.